# What do the braces "[ ]" in the reputation summary mean?

Tags: support

I was taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation and I saw something like this:

```
 2   4391811 (10)
 2   4580949 (10)
 2   4580630 [2]
```

I noticed that I have just another reputation log with `[ ]` and I wonder what it means. Just curious.

In the case above, I didn't accept any answer nor get un-downvoted, so I'm not sure why I earned two points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that you didn't earn the full reputation from that vote as you've hit the reputation cap for the day.

The exception to this is reputation earned from acceptances and bounties. Before the rep cap they are displayed with round brackets, after with square.

Before the rep cap:

> 2       291 (10)
>    1       291 (15)
>    2       291 (10)

and after:

> 2   2676798 [0]
>    1   2676798 [15]
>    2   2676798 [0]

Basically any reputation changing event *after* you've hit the rep cap will be displayed with square brackets. The number inside showing how much reputation (if any) you won or lost (i.e. a down-vote).