# The user page's daily reputation calculation appears to be incorrectly counting an unupvote

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

I have now had suggestions from at least five people that this is a duplicate of one of three other posts. I read and re-read all three of those posts carefully, and they are all discussing different problems. Please *carefully* read the my report below and make sure you understand the bug I am reporting. In particular, if you think this is a duplicate, ensure that the poster of the other report *believes he was awarded the correct number of reputation points.*

---

This was originally discussed in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371733/142445) before we had worked out what the problem actually was. Looking at that answer may provide background information that's not in this rewrite of the issue.

**Nota bene:** This is **not** an example of the perceived problem in [I have a rep to protect. Where is it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262031/142445). I fully agree with the answers to that question about how rep should be calculated, and you can see in the `/reputation` URL output below that the daily rep earned *is* being calculated correctly according to this method. However, the number of points earned that day *is not what is displayed on the user page.*

The other day my user page on [retrocomputing.se] claimed that I'd earned only 205 points for the previous day:

[image: yesterday]

However, according to `/reputation`, I actually earned 215. Both adding up the points for that day manually (including the `[10]`—I don't know what it means that that uses brackets instead of parentheses) and subtracting the cumulative total from the previous day's cumulative total agree on this figure.

```
-- 2021-11-08 rep +200  = 18575
                                 # cumulative total     
 2     22183 (10)                # 10
 2     22183 (10)                # 20
 2     22204 (10)                # 30
 2     22183 (10)                # 40
 2     22204 (10)                # 50
 2     14016 (10)                # 60
 2     22210 (10)                # 70
 2     22210 (10)                # 80
 2     22183 (10)                # 90
 2     22183 (10)                # 100
 2     22197 (10)                # 110
 2     22200 (10)                # 120
 2     22210 (10)                # 130
 2     22210 (10)                # 140
 2     22210 (10)                # 150
 2     22210 (10)                # 160
 2     22204 (10)                # 170
 2     22183 (10)                # 180
 2     22210 (10)                # 190
 2     22183 [10]                # 200
 2     22210 [0]
 2     22210 [0]
 2     22207 [0]
 2     22210 [0]
 2     22197 [0]
 2     22210 [0]
 2     22200 [0]
 1     22200 [15]                # 215
 2     22183 [0]
 2     22200 [0]
 2     22204 [0]
 2     14016 [0]
-- 2021-11-09 rep +215  = 18790
```

Comment: The system is working as intended; see [I have a rep to protect. Where is it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262031/i-have-a-rep-to-protect-where-is-it). Per the answers there, the rep history page on the site shows the -10 as occurring on the day the vote was removed as an **informative** event, to make it clear that you lost rep today, because otherwise people will be wondering where their past rep went. The `/reputation` page, on the other hand, doesn't list informative events and just shows all existing votes and no removed ones.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog If it's working as intended then there's a UI problem. It should make clear that the big "205" number at the top of the day __is not the rep earned today,__ but is instead the rep earned today _with rep lost from other days subtracted from it_. (I am not at all convinced that this is a useful figure, however. Wouldn't it make more sense to show totals earned for the day instead and, when rep is lost from another day, change the total for that day?)

Comment: It wouldn't make sense that way for quite a few users. They'd remember their rep used to be a certain amount but some of that is somehow gone, because a vote cast months or years ago was removed and their today's rep change doesn't show any change. Putting an informative event in today's history makes it clear to users that something changed that day.

Comment: I too think that we should put an informative event in today's history, i.e., that the "-10" should be there. I am confused about what you're disagreeing with. I get the impression that you are stating that its correct for the number at the top to show "205" when 215 rep was earned that day. Is that so?

Comment: This has confused people [for a long time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146682/separate-and-visually-indicate-reversed-events-from-the-days-reputation-changes) but is otherwise by-design.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unupvote immediately followed by an upvote gives me a net -10 reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144512/282094)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125137/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157212/what-happened-to-the-reputation-from-this-unupvote#comment453652_157230 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236424/282094

Comment: @animuson That link appears to be talking about something different: the events that are displayed for the day, not the total displayed for the day. But are you saying that the large number at the top is sometimes _not_ the number of points you received that day, by design? Do you have any links to a description of this design, particularly indicating when that figure should _not_ be the total you earned that day?

Comment: @Rob No. Perhaps you missed my edit where I tried to make it clear that I believe the number of points I'm getting is correct.

Comment: The number at the top is the net change of all reputation changes that occurred that day, inlcuding reversals of past events. It has never been the net change for events that day only. The linked request is to change the behavior to the latter and separate events that affect past days at the bottom to emphasize they are not in the total, to prevent confusion. But it was deemed too complicated.

Comment: @animuson You say, _"...to emphasize they are not in the total, to prevent confusion."_ But the whole point of my report is that that event ___is___ in the total displayed on the user page.

Comment: You're reading my statement as a separate thing. That is *not* how it works currently. The second part of the request is to provide that emphasize *because the request is to make it work that way*.

Comment: Ok, so to be clear again, you're saying that the number at the top of the day is ___not__ the total number of points you received that day_ (but instead a different number, albeit one that often has the same value as the total you received that day), and that is by design? That's fine, in which case perhaps you could post an answer with (or linking to) the official explanation of what that number is.

Comment: Square brackets: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73737/282094

Comment: @Rob Thanks for that! I was wondering what the square brackets meant. However, unless I miscounted (and I added a cumulative total to try to make sure I didn't) or I'm misunderstanding that answer, that introduces the new mystery of why my reputation cap for that day was 190 instead of 200, and for what I was awarded 10 points beyond the reputation cap (which I thought was an upvote).

Comment: If you use the [Time] tab it will [group in time order](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/7208/cjs?tab=reputation&sort=time) which probably makes it easier to spot a cap (200 earned, without including accepts and bounties); and that you have [200 plus an unrecorded upvote (circled) plus an accept (for 15), so 215](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYhXO.png) - but depending on what's earned when, and when votes were reversed, you can cap and obtain more uncredited upvotes with a later reversal. --- The beliefs of the other user in their question doesn't affect whether this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Rob I've always been using the [Time] tab; that's the image I posted. I'm not sure how the uncredited upvote is relevant, since it does not appear to have affected the actual total I received (215, equal to adding together everything but the unupvote, which affected a different day) or the "205" displayed at the top of that day.

Comment: Every comment of yours requests clarification or isn't sure of some point. The more we tell you the further away we are from offering the solution. --- This was closed **6** hours ago, if you disagree you can edit the question to explain why it isn't a duplicate of any other question (discussed or later discovered, and not explained here or elsewhere (such as in the FAQ)) and get it reopened. Otherwise we'll need to assist someone else.

Comment: @Rob What I started with was 215 for 20 upvotes and an accept; what you've said is that I have 215 for 20 upvotes, an accept _and_ an unrecorded upvote. If you're going to bring in new things that don't affect the result in any obvious way, and cannot explain even why you brought it up, you might well do better trying to help someone else with a simpler problem.

Comment: The [**automatic** comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371764/the-user-pages-daily-reputation-calculation-appears-to-be-incorrectly-counting#comment1241834_371764) to which you replied [no, and brought up a reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371764/the-user-pages-daily-reputation-calculation-appears-to-be-incorrectly-counting#comment1241837_371764) that's not going to be considered, was edited to link to [an A's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157212/what-happened-to-the-reputation-from-this-unupvote#comment453652_157230) explaining that.

Comment: @Rob Well, first of all it's not reasonable to expect someone always to see, much less read, an edit to a comment that had already been read and replied to, especially when that edit is just addition of a link without explanation. I hadn't even noticed that the comment had changed. I am also unclear on how the answer "brought up a reason that's not going to be considered." What consideration did you think my "I think my points have been awarded correctly" opinion needed, beyond "Ok, we all agree on that, then"?

Comment: @Rob As for "[an A's comment] explaining that," yes, that comment explains the appearance of the "blank" upvote, matching the `2 22207 [0]` line from `/reputation`. Arguably the appearance of that on the user page is a bug, but it's not the bug I'm reporting, nor does it seem related in any way to the bug I'm reporting. (Regardless that it appeared on the user page, it correctly seems not to change either my actual rep nor the number reported at the head of the day on the user page, which number is the only thing I'm talking about here.)

Comment: There's only 5 minutes to edit a comment, you could have had just the bare automatic comment which you rejected or the additional links. --- You disagree with half a dozen people, that's OK; if you want this reopened it won't be accomplished by commenting.

Comment: @Rob Yes, from the information you have, I _might_ have first seen the edited version. But from the better information I have (I was there), I can assure you that I saw the original version without the extra links and replied to that. But it doesn't really matter, because _none of those links discusses this problem_. They are all about either an incorrect amount of reputation being awarded (unlike my case where it was correctly awarded) or the display below the number at the top of the day (unlike my case, which is about the number at the top of the day).

Comment: @Rob As for re-opening: I've made repeated attempt to explain, e.g., that I believe my points have been _correctly_ awarded, yet people keep voting this as a duplicate of questions where someone believes points have been _incorrectly_ awarded. I could give it a go specifically listing each alleged duplicate and pointing out how what its talking about is not what this question is talking about, but it hardly seems worth the effort.

Comment: FWIW, there does seem to be a correct answer to this question, which is, ["the number beside the day is not the total rep you earned that day, though it usually comes out the same"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371769/what-is-the-number-at-the-top-of-each-day-in-the-reputation-tab-on-the-user-page/371770?noredirect=1#comment1241857_371770) (plus appropriate explanation of that), but I guess this will remain buried in the comments as long as the close-voters refuse to read the actual question here.